# UPDATE and INSERT in the same query when criteria is met

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update, inner-join

What im trying to accomplish is im trying to update a column in a table and insert into a another table if a certain criteria is met.

So far i've tried

```
UPDATE raffles r SET active = 3 INNER JOIN (INSERT INTO raffles_notifs VALUES (uid,raf_id,type) VALUES (r.uid,r.id,1) ) WHERE r.end_stamp = '123123123' AND wuid = 0;
```

This throws an error, it was just a blind attempt. I might even get a few down votes on this, but i really am lost so had to ask

Comment: Try using two separate statements.

Comment: Wouldn't i have to use a sub query in the second statement to get the values to insert.

Comment: Are you asking about `last_insert_id()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two queries. First for update, second for [INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html):

```
UPDATE
    raffles AS r
SET
    active = 3
WHERE
    r.end_stamp = '123123123'
    AND wuid = 0
;

INSERT INTO raffles_notifs (uid,raf_id,type)
    SELECT r.uid, r.id, 1
    FROM raffles AS r
    WHERE
        r.end_stamp = '123123123'
        AND wuid = 0
;
```